# Stop multiple JS sliders interferring with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS beginner here. I've adapted a JS slider to use in a WP theme and it's working fine if there's only one slider per post. If I add a second slider then the total number of slides on the page is counted on the slider controls rather than the number of slides for that particular slider. I know I need to setup some sort of forEach loop but like I said, I'm a beginner so if I could get some help that would be great!

Here's the code:

```js
$('.slideshow-holder').each(function () {

document.getElementById("sliderbutton").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
  });

  document.getElementById("sliderbutton2").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
  });


var currentSlide = 0

var totalSlides = $('.holder div').length

var moveSlide = function (slide) {

    var leftPosition = (-slide * 720) + 'px'

    $('.holder').css('left', leftPosition)
  
  var slideNumber = slide + 1
    $('.steps').text(slideNumber + ' / ' + totalSlides)
}


var nextSlide = function () {
  currentSlide = currentSlide + 1
  
  if (currentSlide >= totalSlides) {
    currentSlide = 0
  }
  moveSlide(currentSlide)
}

var previousSlide = function () {
  currentSlide = currentSlide - 1
  
  if (currentSlide < 0) {
    currentSlide = totalSlides - 1
  } 
  moveSlide(currentSlide)
}

var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
  nextSlide()
}, 3000)

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide)
  nextSlide()
})

$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide)
  previousSlide()
})

var slideNumber = currentSlide + 1
$('.steps').text(slideNumber + ' / ' + totalSlides)

});
```

```css
.slideshow-holder {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.slider-buttons {
  width: 720px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 720px;
  padding-top: 5vh;
}

.holder {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10000vw;
  transition: left 1s;
}

.holder div {
  float: left;
  width: 720px;
  height: 480px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

.slider-controls {
  width: 720px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
 
}

.steps {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: blue;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="slideshow-holder mb4" style="<?php if (get_sub_field('slider_bg') ): ?> background-color: <?php the_sub_field('slider_bg'); ?>;<?php endif; ?>">

  <?php if( have_rows('slides') ): ?>

    <div class="slideshow">

      <div class="holder">

        <?php while(have_rows('slides') ): the_row();?>

          <div class="slide" style="<?php if (get_sub_field('image') ): ?> background-image: url(<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>);<?php endif; ?>"></div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

      </div>

    </div>

  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="slider-controls">
  <a href="#" class="prev" id="sliderbutton" style="<?php if( get_field('page_colour') ): ?>color: <?php the_field('page_colour'); ?>; <?php endif; ?>">Prev</a>
  <a class="steps" style="<?php if( get_field('page_colour') ): ?>color: <?php the_field('page_colour'); ?>; <?php endif; ?>"></a>
  <a href="#" class="next" id="sliderbutton2" style="<?php if( get_field('page_colour') ): ?>color: <?php the_field('page_colour'); ?>; <?php endif; ?>">Next</a>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML and place all of the code in a snippet? It's the button with brackets: <>

Comment: Also, post the name and link to the plugin you're using for the slider.

Comment: I just tried to add a snippet as reqested but I don't think it worked, I'll try again

Comment: Also, this isn't a plugin slider